# Mono mod asp server web api post method not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mono

I am trying to configure mono mod asp server for webapi. It's working fine with get method but Post method gives me strange error.

What I did is I simply created webapi default application and used its default apicontroller without any modification.

Get and Post api is working fine on IIS server. Tried to find the solution but got stuck very bad.

Please help me out.

[image: Error snippet while trying post api]

Comment: It looks like you're not alone: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34011 . It's been reported as a bug but unfortunately hasn't been addressed yet.

Comment: yes, you are right @goobering

Really stuck here.